# Decorating AngularJS Directive template inside the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which is defined, say, as below:

```
angular.module('some-module').directive('someDirective', function() {
  return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: 'true',
  templateUrl: 'some-template.html',
  link: link,
  require: '^form',
  transclude: true,
  scope: {
  decorate: '=',
  }
 };
});
```

Let's say this is how the some-template.html looks (there is more in the actual template though):

```
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

And this is how I will use the directive:

```
<some-directive decorate="true">
  <input name="x" type="number" ng-model="x">
  <input name="y" type="number" ng-model="y">
</some-directive>
<some-directive decorate="false">
  <input name="a" type="number" ng-model="a">
  <input name="b" type="number" ng-model="b">
</some-directive>
```

What I want the directive to do is to manipulate the DOM so that if `decorate` is `true` then, the two input fields should be decorated with some `div`s as below:

```
      <div class="some-outer-class">
           <div class="some-class-1">
              <input name="x" type="number" ng-model="x">
            </div>
            <div class="some-class-2">
               <input name="y" type="number" ng-model="y">
            </div>
            <div><i class="some-glyph-icon"></i></div>
          </div>
```

If the `decorate` attribute is false, or absent, the directive shouldn't do any manipulation.

Couldn't figure out how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply modify the template in link function :

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/jzdS50NxTbfHV7cjMQLU?p=preview)

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
    if(scope.decorate || attrs.decorate != null){
      elem.find('INPUT').wrap('<div class="decorate-class"></div>')
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that the link function is the most logical place to do this DOM manipulation.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this inside the directive. You first define a controller inside your directive as follows:

```
angular.module('some-module').directive('someDirective', function() { 
    var controller = function($scope) {
        //The controller methods
    };
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: 'true',
    templateUrl: 'some-template.html',
    link: link,
    require: '^form',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        decorate: '=',
    },
    controller: controller,
    controllerAs: 'myCtrl'
    };
});
```

Inside the controller, you check the decorate value, and make the DOM manipulation accordingly. You can access the decorate value from your controller via the $scope.

```
var controller = function($scope) {
    if($scope.decorate){
        //Make the DOM manipulation
    }
};
```

DOM manipulation is done as follows:

```
var initialInput = document.querySelector('query'); //You have to select your desired input elements here
var decoratedInput = document.createElement("div");
decoratedInput.className += " some-class-1";
decoratedInput.innerHTML = "<input name='x' type='number' ng-model='x'>";
initialInput.parentNode.replaceChild(decoratedInput, initialInput);
```

Comment: How can manipulate **DOM** in the controller? The controller is no **DOM** element. He need use `link` function!

Comment: of course you can manipulate DOM from controller -) This is actullay recommended way in 1.5.

Comment: He can use methods like angular.element(), or document.getElementById() from the controller and make the manipuation.

Comment: @Faruk Yazıcı of course he can use `angular.element()`, or `document.getElementById()` or even `$('#idElement')`. But this is a bad practice. Link function exist for manipulate with **DOM**.

Comment: @Petr Averyanov How can manipulate DOM in controller? Show example please :-)

Comment: @Faruk Yazıcı manipulating with **DOM** in controller is a **bad** thing. What **query** you put in this `var initialInput = document.querySelector('query');`? Your **template** must have a unique identifier, so that would be in the controller, you can operate it with the correct template directives.